# how to reload same component after refreshing the browser in angular 4 application

Tags: javascript, angular

App Name : Login App

Basically I am logging into the app through login component(http://localhost:4200/login). It redirects it to the admin component if user is there which I am passing in an object. This is running good. but as soon as I refresh the page on admin(http://localhost:4200/admin). I get redirected back to login(http://localhost:4200/login) page. Even if I am logged in successfully.

Here is the necessary code.

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserModel } from './user';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

const USERS = [
  {username: 'admin', password: '12345', role: 'ADMIN'},
  {username: 'user', password: '67890', role: 'USER'}
]

let userObservable = Observable.of(USERS);

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor() { }

  private loginUrl = '/login';
  private redirectUrl = '/admin';
  private loggedInUser: UserModel;
  private isLoggedIn: boolean = false; //This is the value I am making true/false
  getAllUsers(): Observable<UserModel[]> {
    return userObservable;
  }

  isAuthenticated(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.getAllUsers()
      .map(users => {
        let user = users.find(user => (user.username === username) && (user.password === password));
        if(user) {
          this.isLoggedIn = true; 
          this.loggedInUser = user;
        } else {
          this.isLoggedIn = false; 
        }
        return this.isLoggedIn; // boolean value to use found user
      })
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    return this.isLoggedIn;
  }

  getRedirectUrl() {
    return this.redirectUrl;
  }

  setRedirectUrl(url) {
    this.redirectUrl = url;
  }

  getLoginUrl() {
    return this.loginUrl;
  }

  getLoggedInUser(): UserModel {
    return this.loggedInUser;
  }

  logoutUser(): void {
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  }

}
```

**auth-guard.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(activatedRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routerState: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let url: string = routerState.url;
    let user = this.authService.getLoggedInUser();
    if(this.authService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    }
    this.authService.setRedirectUrl(url);
    this.router.navigate([this.authService.getLoginUrl()])
    return false;
  }

}
```

**login.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <p>
    <label for="">Username&nbsp;</label><input type="text" formControlName="username">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="">Password&nbsp;</label><input type="text" formControlName="password">
  </p>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../assets/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'la-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl(),
    password: new FormControl()
  })

  onSubmit(){
    let uname = this.loginForm.get('username').value;
    let pass = this.loginForm.get('password').value;

    this.authService.isAuthenticated(uname, pass).subscribe(
      (authenticated) => {
        if(authenticated) {
          let url = this.authService.getRedirectUrl();  

          this.router.navigate([url]);
        }
      }
    )
  }    
}
```

**app.routing.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { AuthGuardService } from './assets/auth-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
    {'path': '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {'path': 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {'path': 'admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [ AuthGuardService ]},
    {'path': 'user', component: UserComponent}
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class RoutingModule {}
```

**The Reason for redirect to login page after refresh button pressed on browser**: This because when I press refresh app. It reloads everyting and in auth.service (isLoggedIn: boolean = false) is what the application get on reloading the app. So log me out of the application.

My Startegy: I use @ngx-pwa/local-storage to set and get the value like this

// Setting the value on succesfull login

```
this.localStorage.setitem('token','isLoggedIn).subscribe(()=>{})
```

//getting the value on refresh inside canActivate method.Which should compare it with a string value if the value match return true and admin component loads

```
this.localStorage.getitem('token').subscribe((res)=>{ console.log(res) // how to use this value outside of this scope so to compare it with string metioned below})
```

This is the updated code for **login.component.ts**

```
onSubmit(){
    let uname = this.loginForm.get('username').value;
    let pass = this.loginForm.get('password').value;

    this.authService.isAuthenticated(uname, pass).subscribe(
      (authenticated) => {
        if(authenticated) {
          let url = this.authService.getRedirectUrl();
          let user = this.authService.getLoggedInUser();

          this.localStorage.setItem('token', 'isLoggedIn').subscribe(()=>{});

          this.router.navigate([url]);
          console.log(user)
        }
      }
    )
```

This is the updated code for **auth.gaurd service**

```
    checkIsLoggedIn: string;
    canActivate(activatedRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routerState: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        let url: string = routerState.url;
        let user = this.authService.getLoggedInUser();
        this.localStorage.getitem('token').subscribe(
   (res) => { this.checkIsLoggedIn = res } 
)
        if(this.checkIsLoggedIn == 'IsLoggedIn' //here it is getting undefined the value never goes out ) {
          return true;
        }
        this.authService.setRedirectUrl(url);
        this.router.navigate([this.authService.getLoginUrl()])
        return false;
      }
```

How can I manage the state of app in this application so refresh does not breaks the view. or if possible how to use @ngrx localstorage to set/get values and compare them in canActivate method  or is there any other way around.

Comment: why you're not doing it the easy way, you get the token value localStorage.getItem('token') and check if it's defined or not and redirect depending on that

Comment: could  you please show some code @Fateh

Comment: tell me is it a jwt token?

Comment: I am trying to compare it with simple local storage token. please see the auth.gaurd service

Comment: use localStorage.getItem('token') in place of this.localStorage.getitem('token').subscribe(
   (res) => { this.checkIsLoggedIn = res } 
)

Comment: check this https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-route-guards